# Mongo shell not showing databases?

Tags: mongodb

I have various Mongo databases and when I do `ls -l` in my CentOS linux I can see the databaseA.0 and databaseA.ns files for each database and the file size is large enough to tell my data is still there, but when I go to the mongoDB shell by executing the `mongo` command and do a `show dbs` or `show databases` it only shows admin(empty), local 0.078GB, and test(empty).
How do I get my databases back?

Additonal info:
When I start the mongo shell I get the following:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2014-08-15T23:23:14.300-0500 [initandlisten]
2014-08-15T23:23:14.300-0500 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ which can cause issues on versions of RHEL older than RHEL6.
2014-08-15T23:23:14.300-0500 [initandlisten]
2014-08-15T23:23:14.300-0500 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode is 1
2014-08-15T23:23:14.300-0500 [initandlisten] **          We suggest setting it to 0
2014-08-15T23:23:14.300-0500 [initandlisten] **          http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt
2014-08-15T23:23:14.300-0500 [initandlisten]
```

Comment: check your database path...try with `mongod --dbpath /your/path`

Comment: did that...still not joy. There is now a mongod.lock

Comment: is the port correct?

Comment: I'm on the server, does the port matter if I'm accessing it from within the server?

Comment: even on server you must be connecting to mongo shell. when you log in to mongo shell, you need to use correct port/host/dbpath.

Comment: I'm on port 27017. when I did a "lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep mongo" I did a  "telnet localhost 27017" and it stated connected to localhost so I assume it connected properly.

Comment: I would check the `dbpath` used by MongoDB is set to what you expect it to  be. In the `mongo` shell, run: `db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")`. If there is a `dbpath` set it will be listed there; otherwise the path used will be the default of `/data/db`. If the `dbpath` does match up, can you add a pastebin/gist link with an `ls -laR` listing of the data directory as well as the `getCmdLineOpts` output?

Comment: just ran the db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts") and noticed the dbpath is set to dbPath:"/var/lib/mongo", which is not where my databases are contained. Please post this as answer so I can receive notifications on my phone when you respond.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer I think both answers and comments will notify you on the StackExchange mobile app :). Posted an answer with a note on the config file format as well.

Comment: No. Comments will not notify you. That's why I asked. I use the mobile app every day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Checking the `dbpath`

I would check the [`dbpath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) used by MongoDB is set to what you expect it to be.

In the `mongo` shell, run:

```
 db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
```

If there is a `dbpath` set it will be listed there as `parsed.storage.dbPath` (since you are using MongoDB 2.6). If there isn't an explicit setting the `dbpath` will default to `/data/db`.

If a configuration file was used, you should also see a path to the config listed in `parsed.config`.

To fix the `dbpath` you need to update the configuration file and restart `mongod`.

#### Setting the `dbpath`

Note that there are two configuration file formats supported by MongoDB 2.6, so you need to match the format of the existing file:

- [YAML configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) - added in 2.6:

  ```
  storage:
      dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  ```
- [Legacy INI-style config format](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/) - still supported in 2.6, and the likely format if you upgraded from an older version of MongoDB

  ```
  dbpath = /var/lib/mongo
  ```

YAML configurations use semicolons for separators, while the legacy format uses equals signs.

Answer (score 0):

If your mongo client is connected then try `db.repairDatabase()`.For more information [click here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.repairDatabase/)

---

To repair your data files using the `--repairpath` option to preserve the original data files unmodified.

`IMPORTANT`: Always Run `mongod` as the `same user` to avoid changing the permissions of the MongoDB data files.

Start `mongod` using `--repair` to read the existing data files.

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair --repairpath /data/db0
```

When this completes, the new repaired data files will be in the `/data/db0` directory.
Start `mongod` using the following invocation to point the `dbPath` at `/data/db0`:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db0
```

Once you confirm that the data files are operational you may delete or archive the old data files in the `/data/db` directory. You may also wish to move the repaired files to the old database location or update the `dbPath` to indicate the new location.

---

To repair your data files without preserving the original files, do not use the `--repairpath` option, as in the following procedure:

Remove the stale lock file:

```
rm /data/db/mongod.lock
```

Replace `/data/db` with your `dbPath` where your MongoDB instance’s data files reside.

`WARNING`: After you remove the `mongod.lock` file you must run the `--repair` process before using your database.

Start `mongod` using `--repair` to read the existing data files.

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

When this completes, the repaired data files will replace the original data files in the `/data/db` directory.

Start `mongod` using the following invocation to point the `dbPath` at `/data/db`:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db
```

source : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/

Comment: Followed your instructions to the tee and now I have two new folders named after my databases and the lock is still there.

Comment: I updated my answer as per source link..Maybe this will help you.

Comment: I'll try again tomorrow (i mean later)